# when should keystore be in .jks format

Tags: keytool

When I create a keystore using keytool, there is no extension to my keystore file.. it is simply name s"keystore". Recently i saw a keystore with .jks extension. Why is this required and when should I use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can name your Java keystore as you like (see the `-file` option). However, there are other formats (e.g. PKCS#7) for storing keys that are not compatible and therefore it is wise to include an extension that gives you a hint which type of keystore you are dealing with.